# Login Client in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to Typescript/Ionic and trying to figure out how to make a client login. I have the following code in my login page:

```
  login(username, password){      
    var payload = new FormData();
    payload.append("grant_type", 'password');
    payload.append('username', username);
    payload.append('password', password);
    payload.append('client_id', ENV.CLIENT_ID);
    payload.append('client_secret', ENV.CLIENT_SECRET);
    return this.http.post(ENV.API_URL + "/o/token/",payload)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.secureStorage.create('user_data').then((storage:SecureStorageObject) => {
          storage.set('username', username);
          storage.set('password', password);
          storage.set('access_token', data.json()['access_token']);
          storage.set('refresh_token', data.json()['refresh_token']);
        });
      },
      error=>{
        alert('error');
      });
  }
```

This function is being called in the code for a Component when a user clicks a button:

```
this.accountProvider.login(this.username, this.password);
```

Now I realise Typescript is Asynchronous, but I would really like to close the Component when the Login is successful or not when the Login fails. What would be the correct way of doing this in Typescript.

I looked at several examples online but I couldn't find one fitting my needs.

- SecureStorage values should be set in the AccountProvider
- Component Screen closing should happen in the Component code based on outcome of the login.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your problem because this.secureStorage.create('user_data') is Asynchronous ?
If yes, you will need to create and return your own Observable.

Comment: @Gilsdav No, the problem is the fact that the post is asynchronous. I want to make sure the login succeeded before closing the component screen

Comment: The Observable of the Post is easy to go down but if your this.secureStorage.create('user_data') is async too, it's possible that it will not finish to save before closing component. So I explain the two cases on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are waiting on the post to be finished, your code basically has the opportunity staring right at you.  In the `.subscribe(data => )` part of your code you are subscribing to the post, and when it emits the data you perform all of the actions :
          `storage.set('username', username);
          storage.set('password', password);
          storage.set('access_token', data.json()['access_token']);
          storage.set('refresh_token', data.json()['refresh_token']);`
This guarantees that the data has been emitted before these things are performed. Similarly, if you wanted to close the component after the post is finished, you simply add a line of code in the ends of these four lines and it should work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

**Because of your this.secureStorage.create('user_data') is asynchronous too, you need to do your own observable:**

```
login(username, password){     
    return Observable.create((observer) => { 
        var payload = new FormData();
        payload.append("grant_type", 'password');
        payload.append('username', username);
        payload.append('password', password);
        payload.append('client_id', ENV.CLIENT_ID);
        payload.append('client_secret', ENV.CLIENT_SECRET);
        return this.http.post(ENV.API_URL + "/o/token/",payload)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.secureStorage.create('user_data').then((storage:SecureStorageObject) => {
                storage.set('username', username);
                storage.set('password', password);
                storage.set('access_token', data.json()['access_token']);
                storage.set('refresh_token', data.json()['refresh_token']);
                observer.onNext();
                observer.onCompleted();
            }, () => {
                observer.onError();
                observer.onCompleted();
            });
        },
        error=>{
            alert('error');
            observer.onError();
            observer.onCompleted();
        });
    }
}
```

**In the case you only have post as asynchronous use .do() function**

The .do() doesn't contains async call so we will imagine that "storage" already exist.

```
  login(username, password){      
    var payload = new FormData();
    payload.append("grant_type", 'password');
    payload.append('username', username);
    payload.append('password', password);
    payload.append('client_id', ENV.CLIENT_ID);
    payload.append('client_secret', ENV.CLIENT_SECRET);
    return this.http.post(ENV.API_URL + "/o/token/",payload)
    .do(data => {
        storage.set('username', username);
        storage.set('password', password);
        storage.set('access_token', data.json()['access_token']);
        storage.set('refresh_token', data.json()['refresh_token']);
    });
}
```

You will be able to use it (in the two cases) like this:

```
this.accountProvider.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
  () => {console.log('onSuccess')},
  () => {console.log('onError')},
  () => {console.log('onCompleted')}
);
```

You can see that "onCompleted" is called when onSuccess and onError fire.